# Convert dom4j.Element to dom4j.Document

Tags: java, dom4j

Lets assume sometimes I got a dom4j Document and sometimes I got a dom4j Element. I want to apply the code of the following function

```
public List<Element> getElements(Document doc4j){
//do
}
```

on my object of type Element as well. But that would only work if I can convert this Element to a Document. I cant use the method `getDocument`, because I only want to apply the code under *//do* for the sub tree which represented by the object of type Element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Branch.html), it looks like Document and Element both extend Branch, can you not make your method take a Branch as below?

```
public List<Element> getElements(Branch branch) {
  //do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given an `Element` (or any other node) call `getDocument()` do get the document to which the element belongs.

Comment: But the I get the whole Document and not only the sub tree, which is represented by the element.

Comment: @StellaMaris your question does not express that clearly